# Parse only a selected JSON node, using GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

Through a web service that I can't change, I am getting a JSON response in the following format:

```
{
    "response": {
        "profile": {
            "id": 8873,
             ....
             ....
       }
    }
}
```

I am using Retrofit with GSON to finally use the parsed JSON stored in a POJO.

Is there a way through which I can directly get the data that's inside the `profile` object, in a POJO, and skip processing `response` ?

I basically don't want to write an extra class to hold an object of `response`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [json lib](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/2.4), you can first get response body out and then use gson to turn this json string to POJO like this.

```
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
public void partJson() {
    String response = "{\n" +
            "    \"response\": {\n" +
            "        \"profile\": {\n" +
            "            \"id\": 8873\n" +
            "       }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}";

    JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject().fromObject(response);
    JSONObject jsonObject = responseObject.optJSONObject("response");

}
```